# VisualSVN commit-hook add revision to a file in the repo

Tags: svn, visualsvn, pre-commit-hook, post-commit-hook

We have a PHP Project under SVN control(VisualSVN).

Somehow, i need to update a file in the repo with the current revision number.
So that when the main site gets updated/checkout we can show the svn build number (this part is not the issue).

is it possible with a pre/post-commit-hook to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a build solution, rather than a pre-commit hook. Using a build system like Apache Ant, you could grab the latest revision number from the repository when preparing your solution for the live environment.

Edit: To actually answer your question "is it possible with a pre/post-commit-hook to do this?" yes it is technically possible but as already suggested, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

pre and post-commit-hooks behave differently (see the documentation in the [SVN red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks) about the hooks and especially the part about [implementing the hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)):

- pre-commit: Check if the commit is allowed. So the pre-commit hook is not able at all to change anything inside the commit.
- post-commit: Notifies about a successful commit.

So no mention of the chance to change anything. Instead, there is a paragraph in the section "implementing the hooks":

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.

So I would say, it is not possible or at least recommended to do that.

Answer (score 0):

While mliebelt quoted the right text, he made bad conclusion. Even twice:

- It have to be done in post-commit hook
- It's impossible to do in hook

**Second statement**

If post-commit hook will rewrite *file not included in this commit*, it will be perfectly valid operation, which broke nothing.

**First statement**

This solution is clearly bad for a lot of reasons:

- you include in repository (in order to reference later on it) data, which is depend from overall repository data-changes, but: **every change of data in this file change also state of repository data**. Classical vicious circle
- you increase amount of **required** revisions **twice**: after each "data-revision" you have to perform "tracking-revision"
- you want VCS was engaged to other's problems, more applicable to build-deploy tools, for VCS *having this data* is enough

Repository (or Working Copy of) per se **have** information about last revision in it (`svn info`, `svnversion`, `svn log -r HEAD`), storing it inside data violates Occam's Raroz. You have only extract data, when you "publish" data for using outside repository.

Which tools and how to use is heavy-dependent from: deploy workflow, OS (you haven't gawk-grep-sed on ordinary Win-box), just some hints:

- SubWCRev (Win-only) from TortoiseSVN can inspect Working Copies and process template-files by replacing special SubWCRev's keywords by actual values. SubWCRev have sister's projects for Linux-world. Using these tools assumes storing template-file *somewhere* (inside or outside repo) and saving processed result inside prepared to usage project-tree
- svnversion and svnlook can be used in any OS (for WC-path and repository-path accordingly)

And at last

- You **can** use Subversion keywords for storing revision number **inside repo**, just don't forget, that $Revision$, used inside file, reflects **revision of last changes in this file** and have predefined format after expansion

Answer (score 0):

What about requiring developers to update the file themselves and then using a pre-commit script to refuse commits where the update is incorrect?  Perhaps the insertion of a revision number is a responsibility better incorporated into one's editor or build process / deploy scripts.